# Joomla FTP::mkdir bad response

Tags: php, joomla

I know there are so many solutions about this error, but nothing helped.

I searched in google and found few solutions:

[Here](http://servert.wordpress.com/2011/09/15/how-to-fix-the-jftp-error-in-joomla-jftpstore-bad-response-%E2%80%93-warning-%E2%80%93-failed-to-move-file/)

[and here](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=314112)

[and here too](http://www.joomlart.com/forums/showthread.php?14087-JFTP-store-Bad-response)

and few more, **but nothing helped**.

I'm using joomla FTP uploader class and a i found out, everything seems to be OK.

```
jimport('joomla.client.ftp');

$host = 'host.myhost.com';
$port = 21;
$options = null;
$user = 'xx';
$pass = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
$dir = 'tmp_users/' . $this -> user -> id;
//echo $dir;

$ftp_ob = new JFTP();
$ftp = $ftp_ob -> getInstance($host, $port, $options, $user, $pass);

if ($ftp -> isConnected()) {

    if (!is_dir($dir)) {
        $ftp -> mkdir($dir);
        $ftp -> create($dir . '/index.html');
        $ftp -> write($dir . '/index.html', '<!DOCTYPE html><title></title>');
    }
}
```

My goal is to make user_id named directory and upload some files and document there.

```
public $ftp_enable = '0';
```

also, chmod main directory to 777, of course, chmod configuration.php and so on. The main problem is that, at first page reload, directory is being created fine, everything is ok, and when i refresh page, error occurs. I tried to check

> if is_dir

but did not work. At least I checked joomla/client/ftp.php and found that line, telling me nothing.

```
public function mkdir($path)
{
    // If native FTP support is enabled let's use it...
    if (FTP_NATIVE)
    {
        if (ftp_mkdir($this->_conn, $path) === false)
        {
            // HERE IS WHAT MAKES ME NERVOUS BREAKDOWN
            JError::raiseWarning('35', JText::_('JLIB_CLIENT_ERROR_JFTP_MKDIR_BAD_RESPONSE_NATIVE'));
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    // Send change directory command and verify success
    if (!$this->_putCmd('MKD ' . $path, 257))
    {
        JError::raiseWarning('35', JText::sprintf('JLIB_CLIENT_ERROR_JFTP_MKDIR_BAD_RESPONSE', $this->_response, $path));
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**I use joomla 2.5**

Comment: Did you check the Joomla Issue tracker for any issues regarding this? I already assume you are running the latest version in the 2.5.x series...

Comment: yeap, I checked and the only solution I found, is 2.5 standart bug with different ftp servers and OSes.

Comment: If there is already a patch for that bug, you can contribute testing it.